# During major upgrade prompt user for version upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I have built an msi installer using WIX. And as per the requirement I have to give an upgrade for next build. So, I checked about the upgrade, types of upgrade, its implementation steps and found Major upgrade will be suitable for us. So, as per steps I changed Package code, Product code and version number (increment the version) in project main .wxs file and generate the build which is upgrading properly (for that I checked in registry, Control Panel, etc...).

Major upgrade build is migrating features properly but user has no information whether installer is upgrading or doing the fresh installation. I am expecting an message like "The setup has been upgrading from v1.0.0.0 to v2.0.0.0. Do you want to continue" as user is going for installation.

Note: In my project I am having only 2 custom dialogs else rest all dialogs (e.x. Welcome dialog, EULA dialog, InstallDir dialog, etc...) are by default coming from WixUIExtension.dll.

I explored few links & blogs related to major upgrade but I didn't got proper solution related to this. Please share your valuable comments & what is the best way / practice for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a major upgrade by checking the UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE property.  You would then need a custom action to query MSI for the ProductVersion of that installed product.  Finally you'd have to ask the user and proceed or abort.

How do you plan on handling silent installations?  Just automatically proceed or require them to pass a property such as  AGREETOUPGRADE=1  ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a major upgrade, assuming you're using the WiX majorupgrade tag, then the WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property is set. You could use that to condition a dialog to be shown. That property value will be the ProductCode of the older product, so you'd do something like MsiGetProductInfo (ProductCode, ....INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING....) to get its version. The dialog will presumably need a cancel to abort the upgrade.

You may run into issues because retrieving the ProductVersion may require elevation. In general, nobody bothers to verify upgrades like this because your customers are smarter than that. They know if the install is upgrading a new product or not and the fewer questions you ask the happier they are.